# Procedural wood bark displacement shader

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I am trying the generate a procedural wood bark with the displacement material slot (in object texture coordinate).

I got this result:

[image]

It's still far from the effect i am trying to create, here is the result i want to get:

[image]

It must be generated on a cylinder with a radius of 30 cm to be close to a tree.

Comment: So what *specifically* is your question?

Comment: It looks like you are heading in the right direction. Just need to add more complexity to the texture that is driving the displacement. Mix different textures at different scales.